# Python:how to understand assignment and reference?

Tags: python, variable-assignment

the python code section are following lines:

```
>>> values = [0, 1, 2]
>>> values[1] = values
>>> values
[0, [...], 2]
```

why the value is `[0,[...],2]`,what is `...`? why the value is not `[0,[0,1,2],2]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[...]` means you self-referenced the variable to itself (cyclic reference):

```
>>> values = [0, 1, 2]
>>> sys.getrefcount(values) #two references so far: shell and `values`  
2
>>> values[1] = values     #created another reference to the same object but a cyclic one
>>> sys.getrefcount(values) # references increased to 3
3
>>> values[1] is values  # yes both point to the same obejct
True
```

Now you can modify the object using either `values` or `values[1]`:

```
>>> values[1].append(4)
>>> values
[0, [...], 2, 4]
#or
>>> values[1][1][1].append(5) 
>>> values
[0, [...], 2, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

You created a recursive reference; you replaced the item at index `1` with a reference to whole list.

To display that list now, Python does *not* recurse into the nested reference and instead displays `[...]`.

```
>>> values = [0, 1, 2]
>>> values[1] = values
>>> values
[0, [...], 2]
>>> values[1] is values
True
```

Referencing `values[1]` is the *same thing* as referencing `values`, and you can do so ad infinitum:

```
>>> values[1]
[0, [...], 2]
>>> values[1][1] is values
True
>>> values[1][1] is values[1]
True
```

Answer (score 2):

[...] is a list ... in this case a list within a list.

You assign the second item of values to itself so the complete values list is inserted (or referenced).

A short test:

```
values = [0, 1, 2]
values[1] = values
print values
v = values[1]
print v
v[1] = 5
print values
```

prints

```
[0, [...], 2]
[0, [...], 2]
[0, 5, 2]
```

As you can see, when changing values[1][1] (which is v[1])) is does not change that particular item, but the reference itself, otherwise it would be [0, [0, 5, 2], 2].